# How to use $(this) on keypress

Tags: jquery, html, this

I have a method defined on `keyPress` event of input. Same method is called on multiple input controls.

I need to read value in the current control. I am not able to use `this` keyword. Can someone help, how can I use `this` keyword.

**Script**:

```
function isNumberKey(e,obj) {
    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
    var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || keyCode == 46);
    var inp = $(this).val();
    alert(inp);
    // rest code goes here
    return ret;
}
```

**HTML** :

```
<input type="text" id="inpt1" onkeypress="javascript: return isNumberKey(event,this)"/>
<input type="text" id="inpt2" onkeypress="javascript: return isNumberKey(event,this)"/>
```

Comment: use `var inp = $(obj).val();`

Comment: thanx mate.. working.. saved my time

Comment: glad it is working now mate happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accsess obj as:

```
var inp = $(obj).val();
```

Comment: may be you missed some syntax  :)